# if/else redirect output to empty variable in batch file

Tags: windows, redirect, batch-file, if-statement, string

Here is my code:

```
IF "%LOGFILE%" NEQ "" (
    CALL :DO_SOMETHING 2>&1> %LOGFILE%
) ELSE (
    CALL :DO_SOMETHING
)
```

The issue I am facing is that the IF/ELSE statement is treated as one big statement and the statement as a whole needs to be syntactically correct.  So if "%LOGFILE%" does equal "", the first CALL statement would not be syntactically correct (even though it would never get called in this scenario), making the whole IF/ELSE statement syntactically incorrect.

How can I get around this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
IF "%LOGFILE%" NEQ "" (
    SET logfile_redirection=2^>^&1^> %LOGFILE%
) ELSE (
    SET logfile_redirection=
)
CALL :DO_SOMETHING %logfile_redirection%
```

Comment: Thanks!  I have not tried it out yet but looks like it should work.  Just wondering why I would need to escape the '>' and '&' though.

Comment: If you don't escape them it treats them as an attempt to redirect the output of the `SET` command, and generates a syntax error exactly as per your original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
SET logfile_redirection=2>&1> %LOGFILE%
IF "%LOGFILE%"=="" SET "logfile_redirection="
CALL :DO_SOMETHING %logfile_redirection%
```

Quotes for SET are not required, but ensures that there are no trailing spaces.

Comment: This doesn't work when `LOGFILE` isn't set.  Did you test it?